# What is this plant with long narrow leaflets?

Tags: identification, houseplants, palm

I bought a plant a few weeks ago and I don't know its name. I'm not quite sure how to take care of it. Can you help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plant is an [Areca palm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dypsis_lutescens), (Dypsis lutescens) which is native to Madagascar but naturalized across the world.  When grown outside in Florida they can reach heights of 20' (~6 M). Indoors they are seen in a range from 3' to 6' (~1 to 2 M).

When grown indoors bright filtered light is the best filtered environment. Water thoroughly when the top inch of the soil is dry.

This plant can be attacked by [spider mites](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spider_mite), [mealy bug](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mealybug) and [thrip](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Thrips).  The most common pest, spider mite, tends to occur when the plant is placed in low light for extended periods or bright hot dry conditions.

- Soap and water applied at a rate of  teaspoon/quart (~5ml/liter) three times over six day periods will control spider mite.
- With mealybug and thrip I just got rid of the plants as these pests were very hard to bring under control and spread easily.
- Fertilize after a few years with 20-20-20 at half the recommended strength.
- Top up the soil yearly with a soil less mix
- Remove the fruiting bodies as they attract pests.

Comment: Thanks! Is blazing sun (behind glass) acceptable for it? Or does that harm?

Comment: Hot and dry conditions such as next to a south window in a house with central heating will stress the plant due to the low humidity and encourage spider mites.  Just pull the plant back a foot or so from the window.  Morning sun is fine as it not too hot.