# Indoor Majesty Palm has yellowing leaves that also have brown tinges - too much water or not enough?

Tags: watering, sunlight, palm, repotting, water

Help!! My majesty palm now has 20% of its large leaves being mostly yellow... There are brown tinges on many of the leaves, including the green ones.

I am not sure if this is too much or too little water? (Just misted it. It's usually in the bathroom, indirect sunlight.)

Does it need more sun or less?

I just repotted it 2 days ago to a larger pot with wheels and a watering system that's from the base. Hope that gets water straight to the root ball while keeping the upper soil more dry.

[image]

Comment: Just looks like old leaves dying.  Look around at other palms out in the open, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As it is the older frond that is yellowing it should be cut off cleanly with gardening clippers or shears or sequitur.

I see you have fungus gnats that you are trying to control with yellow sticky traps. That can be quite effective but another factor that increases their numbers is wet organic based soil mix.  If you re potted with a "soil less mix" that is mostly peat moss this and lots of water are ideal conditions for fungus gnats

- move to higher light, these plants can handle indirect light all day even in tropical climates. You can accustom them to direct sun by placing them with a morning exposure.
- Continue to use the sub surface you have for watering.  Most palms have a vigorous root system and will have their roots down at the reservoir in no time. Watering from the top should not be required unless the whole root ball dries out.
- check for spider mites.  These are very common on palms and live on the underside of the frond. They can be seen without magnification and look like tiny grains of salt. This [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/19826/499) has more details

Comment: do you know if this is because i am overwatering - and yes, this is supposed to be one of those automatic watering systems where you water from the bottom and in theory the plant sucks up what it needs? i've let it sit dry for a few days after noticing brown/yellow

Comment: @ina theoretically you cannot overwater using the automatic watering system.  But repotting can stress a plant.  Just cut the frond off and try the suggestions in my answer